# Passing html data from a div to php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to get the total text data from a contentEditable div, but I would like to pass the data just as it is in the div with the HTML elements in tact to a PHP file. At the moment only the text is being returned by log stripped of html tags,

---

First I dynamically add this to the div

```
       var user = "<a contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+name+" </a>";
       $("#message").append(user);
```

---

But when I try to log the content I only see the text within the 'a' tag returned

```
         var msg = $('#message').html();
         console.log(msg);
```

---

THi is my HTML

```
        <div name="message" contentEditable="true" id="message" ></div>
```

So an Example of what I would like to pass is this

```
        "Hello world!<a href='#'>Ned</a> Fails!"
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you're saying `$("#message").append(user);` but you don't have a div id `message`, only a div with id `chat-message`. Is that related or just a question typo?

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out, just a typo when I was making this question. I corrected my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ktraff/4nYYN/1/) for a working copy to what I think your looking for.  Looks like you just need to ensure the id's of your elements match:

```
$(function () {
  var name = "Ned";
  var user = "<a contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+name+" </a>";
  $("#message").append("Hello world!" + user + " Fails!");
   var msg = $('#message').html();
   alert(msg);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.html()` function returns code of child elements.
It does not return the HTML code of the element itself. 
Use $("#message").parent().html() to access element's parent.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending your data in element with id -"message"...

```
$("#message").append(user);
```

but taling html of element with id -"chat-message"

```
$('#chat-message').html();
```

so where is your chat-message element?? might be you are making mistake in choosing the element to display html..